# for range loop with const& argument when the iterable itself is passed by a const& argument

Tags: c++11, pass-by-reference

If I pass a container by constant reference, is there a point in declaring a constant reference in a range-for loop, or will the elements in the loop automatically inherent that property?

i.e.

```
int foo(std::vector<int> const& vec) {
    for (int const& el : vec)
        // do something...
}
```

is the above equivalent to:

```
int foo(std::vector<int> const& vec) {
    for (int el : vec)
        // do something...
}
```

Comment: You can't have a nonconst reference. But you don't have a reference at all in the second example; There the argument simply gets copied.

Comment: @Cubic I'm not sure what you mean, you can say `for (int& el : vec) { ... modify el here... }`. I guess I'm asking if you pass by const reference in the function (thus not copying the container), what are you copying from when you don't pass by reference in the loop?

Comment: Your second loop has `el` declared as `int` instead of `int&`, so it gets a copy instead of a reference.

Answer (score 1):

For a trivial scalar like an int, a const reference is just overhead - behind the scenes references are implemented with pointers, so a reference is really just a compiler-managed pointer and accessing it requires a dereference.

```
#include <vector>

extern void f1(int);
extern void f2(int const&);

int foo1(std::vector<int> const& v) {
  for (int const& val: v) {
    f1(val);
    f2(val);
  }
}

int foo2(std::vector<int> const& v) {
  for (int val: v) {
    f1(val);
    f2(val);
  }
}
```

[Assembly output](http://%20%20%20%20#include%20%3Cvector%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20extern%20void%20f1(int);%20%20%20%20%20extern%20void%20f2(int%20const&);%20%20%20%20%20%20int%20foo1(std::vector%3Cint%3E%20const&%20v)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(int%20const&%20val:%20v)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f1(val);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f2(val);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20int%20foo2(std::vector%3Cint%3E%20const&%20v)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(int%20val:%20v)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f1(val);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f2(val);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%7D)

foo2 produces this:

```
    movl    (%rbx), %edi     ; val = *it
    addq    $4, %rbx         ; ++it
    movl    %edi, 12(%rsp)   ; save val on stack
    call    f1(int)
    leaq    12(%rsp), %rdi   ; load address of saved val
    call    f2(int const&)
```

Note the `leaq` for calling `f2`. We took a simple copy of the current vector value into `edi`, but then we also had to push it onto the stack so we could get an address to comply with the reference requirement for `f2`.

However in a different example, the compiler is perfectly capable of figuring out that a reference wasn't needed and just doing the right thing:

```
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>

int total;

int foo1(std::vector<int> const& v) {
  for (int const& val: v) {
    total += val;
  }
}

int foo2(std::vector<int> const& v) {
  for (int val: v) {
    total += val;
  }
}
```

[both functions produce the same code](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:'-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B14',sourcez:AQ4YgSwOwYwGwK4BMCmwA8A3FMAuB7AJwD4AoUcaeZNdAQwIFsIYyLzRpdgDc64A3KQ4guwAGb58ARgAUAZ1xIAXMux4i6LsWAx8URQDJgmAJTAA3iNCTCwWWL0HcxzP2UnzVihV79gANQAvCb8Qj7AAL7W0aQAkGKS%2BABMCkqq6gSEWlC4Ok5GnpbWILb2Ym5wHmbFESB%2BcIEhleE%2B0RTRQAAA%3D)),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3), the compiler eliminated the reference.